# TortoiseSVN checkout via LAN

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have recently installed [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) on Windows and have two computers, A and B. On both machines I installed TortoiseSVN and they are connected via LAN, and I have my repository saved in computer A.

I want to access/checkout the repository in Computer A from Computer B, so I tried this URL in the repository to SVN checkout from Computer B,

```
http://192.168.2.6/Repository
```

but I got an error message as:

> repository moved permanently to 'http://192.168.2.6/Repository'; please relocate

I tried some other URLs as well like,

```
http://192.168.2.6/C:/wamp/www/Repository/
http://192.168.2.6///C:/wamp/www/Repository/
file:///192.168.2.6///C:/wamp/www/Repository/
```

These didn't work either... What am I missing? What URL and settings should I be using to access?
Or what is the procedure to create a Subversion repository locally and access it in a group of computers connected via LAN/WAN?

Comment: The error that you're getting is a problem with the Apache configuration on computer A.  Can you provide that configuration?

Comment: I got the solution, I didnt actually have a SVN server installed, with which i could retrieve the repository through a specific URL.
I installed VisualSvn and that solved the problem .

Answer (score 1):

Within your filemanager (or Windows Explorer), right click within a directory. There should be the entry *TortoiseSVN*. Then select *Project archive*. In the next window you'll see *URL*. That's the one you must change.